# I would like to replace the default image on the Homepage slideshow with the .SVG file that I have created

Tags: wordpress, svg, shopify, shopify-template

I have created a .SVG file on Adobe Illustrator.
I  would like to replace the default image on the Homepage slideshow with the .SVG file that I have created. I am using the Shopify platform.
Any support would be greatly appreciated. Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Remove the  tag with the default image you do not like. Paste in the  code you do like. Usually your home page is in index.liquid template.

1:1 swap out!

Comment: There is no tag in index.liquid template.. just this code "{{ content_for_index }}" I also want to add new slider images as .SVG file.How can I do that?

Comment: Your theme has a customization button. Press it. Examine your home page settings. Figure out which section you are using. Then go edit that section, as it has your <img> tags.